# How to Load a Signin https:// page in a http:// Page

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I have a normal HTTP page where in top header section I have a Sign in Link. On click of sign in link a twitter style Flyout sign in window appears, which should be a secured signin section.

Can any one suggest me how could I achieve loading a HTTPS page or section in a HTTP page.

Thanks

Comment: Don't secure just your sign in. Secure your whole site. When people go to log in, move the entire session over the HTTPS. Otherwise you get [the Firesheep problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firesheep).

Answer (score 1):

The contents of the flyout should be an iframe. In there you can have a https page.

Answer (score 1):

May be it won't work because there would be a Cross domain posting and page would be blocked by the browser.

Comment: It would only not work if you want do do something that transverses the partnt/child boundary, like calling something in the iframe from the parent or vice versa. As long as you handle the whole login shebang in the iframe there is no cross domain calls.